# How to use row value in where clause with sequelize API

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I want to achieve this sql query using sequelize.

```
select id, date, comment
from posts
where (date, id) > ('2018-01-01', 1)
order by date, id
limit 10
```

This kind of query is used for infinite scroll pagination. Any idea on how to do this? The docs doesn't say anything about row value

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is the `where`, you can rewrite it as:

```
where date > '2018-01-01' or (date = '2018-01-01' and id > 1)
```

Comment: @GorgonLinoff I was thinking in doing this. But do you know if this have any impact on the performance of the query on Postgres?

Comment: @GuilhermeCaraciolo . . . You will need to try on your data.  I suspect that this could affect performance if you have an index on `(date, id)`.

Answer (score 1):

As @GondonLinoff pointed out the query can be rewrite.
I had analyzed the performance of the two queries on postgres using `explain analyze` and it doesn't have any impact (seems that row value is only syntax sugar, but an dba expert could explain this).

So, in sequelize the where clause should be implemented as:

```
const filter = {}
filter[Op.or] = [
  {
    date: {
      [Op.gt]: sinceDate
    }
  },
  {
    [Op.and]: {
      date: sinceDate,
      id: {
        [Op.gt]: sinceId
      }
  }
}
const result = await Posts.findAll({ where: filter })
```