# How to postgresql sequelize query on json array

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

How to write the sequelize where query on medium and subject over the PostgreSQL table in NodeJs?

E.g.
select * from tablename where params.medium IN("Hindi", "English") AND params.subject IN("Hindi","Science");

here table column name is **params**

**Data** in params column:

```
{
   "board":"CBSE",
   "medium":[
      "Hindi",
      "English",
      "Urdu"
   ],
   "subject":[
      "Hindi",
      "Mathematics",
      "Science"
   ]
}
```

Comment: check out this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/48369512/12761193

Comment: @Arya thanks for the solution. you are my lifesaver :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have done as following

```
   const Op = Sequelize.Op;


    const filter = {
      [Op.and]: [{
        [Op.or]:[
          {
            'params.medium': {
              [Op.regexp]: 'Hindi'
            }
          },
          {
            'params.medium': {
              [Op.regexp]: 'English'
            }
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        [Op.or]:[
          {
            'params.subject': {
              [Op.regexp]: 'Hindi'
            }
          },
          {
            'params.subject': {
              [Op.regexp]: 'Science'
            }
          }
        ],
      }
    ]};

    model.findAll({
        where: {
          ...filter
        }
   )};
```

Please suggest if any better solution.